# Problem with NSDateFormatter

Tags: iphone, nsdateformatter

I want to display the time as 8:00a instead of 8:00AM. How to do this? I have used

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mma"];
```

Any help.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the supported [unicode](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

I think you have to follow some logic achieve this,

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"hh:mma"];//Convert Date to String in a Common Format
NSString *dateString = [dateFormat  stringFromDate:date];  
dateString=[dateString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"AM" withString:@"a"];
dateString=[dateString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"PM" withString:@"p"];
```

EDIT:

You can also do as,

```
[dateFormat setPMSymbol:@"p"];
[dateFormat setAMSymbol:@"a"];
```